# How word2Vec or wod2Doc understand user sentiments

Tags: nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I have gone through numerous documents to read about doc2Vec and word2Vec. I do understand how powerful it is to represent the words as a vector and to perform simple operations like vector addition , subtraction to yield meaningful analogy between the words. 
Although one thing I am still not able to understand is how this technique can be used to understand user sentiments .

Can someone please elaborate as to how user sentiments are analysed using these techniques ?
Thanks
Samir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By representing a document or set of words with feature vectors, you can process text in other machine learning tasks. For example if you have a dataset which labeled each document `x` with its sentiment `y`, you can use the pretraind embedding as feature vectorisation to represent `x` as input to your machine learning method and test if these features help your task.